# How do you save an array to session storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, session-storage

I've read a few similar threads, but the solutions are not working for me. The page I am working on has filters for a gallery of images. Each time I click on a filter the images with reload according to that filter via a JSON file.

If I want to apply multiple filters I would need the ones chosen prior to the reload to save in an array variable.

This is the code I have for this

```
let filterArray = []

sessionStorage.setItem('filterArray', JSON.stringify(filterArray))

let savedArr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('filterArray'))
```

Right now I don't have the page reload set up but after clicking on a filter and refreshing the page I would expect to be able to log the 'savedArr' variable but when I do I get this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: savedArr is not defined
>       at :1:13

Comment: Where do you do your `console.log(savedArr )` ?

Comment: I tried both in the console and in the file directly below savedArr

Answer (score 0):

You can't log `savedArr` after you refresh the page, you need to redefine it.

The data in session storage will persist, but your variable declarations will not.

Call the declaration line again after you reload the page and you will have access to the data.

`let savedArr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('filterArray'))`

Comment: How exactly do you redefine it? I don't quite understand

Comment: You call your 3rd line again.